# how to use self field in models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model with foreigns. I want to limit the choices for it with depend on content of another field of this model.

This code works:

```
class PhysicalProperty(models.Model):
    property_quantity = models.ForeignKey(Quantity)    
    default_unit = models.ForeignKey(MeasurementUnits, limit_choices_to = {'quantity': 1 )
```

But it takes from MeasurementUnits all records with MeasurementUnits.quantity = 1. And I need to set query as MeasurementUnits.quantity = PhysicalProperty.property_quantity.

This code doesn't work

```
class PhysicalProperty(models.Model):
    property_quantity = models.ForeignKey(Quantity)    
    default_unit = models.ForeignKey(MeasurementUnits, limit_choices_to = {'quantity': property_quantity )
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set a Quantity to a default_unit which sets a foreignkey to a MeasurementUnits? Is MeasurementUnits a subclass of Quantity?

Comment: I have 3 model : Quantity (length, mass, volume etc), MeasureUnits (metr and foot for length, gramm for mass, litre for volume etc) and PhysicalProperty (with foreign key both to Quantity and MeasureUnits)  And I need to have the list of measureunits for PhysicalProperty.default_units, which a allowed to PhysicalProperty.Quantity

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzvL7oMbj907cGpaVk5Sc3dhc1E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems quire similar to one I have recently [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23313293/2013920). Please take a look and try analogical solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use self in class. self is for instances of classes.

you could use the init method for that

```
class PhysicalProperty(models.Model):
    property_quantity = models.ForeignKey(Quantity)    
    default_unit = models.ForeignKey(MeasurementUnits)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super(self, PhysicalProperty).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.default_unit = self.property_quantity
```

that way, everytime you do `physical_property = PhysicalProperty()`, `physical_property.default_unit` will be the same as property_quantity of the same object.

Comment: This is a method to assign the initial value to PhysicalProperty.default_unit. But i need to have the list of measureunits for PhysicalProperty.default_units, which a allowed to PhysicalProperty.Quantity (see db design https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzvL7oMbj907cGpaVk5Sc3dhc1E/edit?usp=sharing)